# VLOOKUP return an array for SMALL function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to use VLOOKUP to return an array for the SMALL function so that I can evaluate the X smallest values based on the lookup. The lookup table is as the image shows.
[image]

The image above is from the 'How Many to Use' worksheet. I'm using the following formula `=VLOOKUP(COUNTA($N9:AA9),'How Many to Use'!A2:C14,3)` but Excel chokes (#VALUE) on my formula because it returns the array expected but returns it as text, not the true array I'm hoping for for the SMALL function. **Is there a way to convert this to an actual array?**

The full formula in context is trying to average use a certain number of values within the array in my main worksheet and averaging the smallest X values based on the full count in the row's values.

```
=IF(COUNT($N9:Z9)<>0,IF(COUNT($N9:Z9)<=3,AVERAGE($N9:Z9),SUM(SMALL(INDEX($N9:Z9,MATCH(TRUE,COLUMN($N9:Z9)=LARGE(NOT(ISBLANK($N9:Z9))*COLUMN($N9:Z9),COUNTA($N9:AA9)),0)):Z9,VLOOKUP(COUNTA($N9:AA9),'How Many to Use'!A2:C14,3)))/VLOOKUP(COUNTA($N9:AA9),'How Many to Use'!A2:C14,2)),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting narrowly and working outward:

**(1)** To directly answer your question, you could convert the string to an array using VBA, eg:

```
Function Eval(formulaText As String, Optional stable As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Application.Volatile Not stable
    Eval = Evaluate(formulaText)
End Function
```

`=Eval(VLOOKUP(COUNTA($N9:AA9),'How Many to Use'!A2:C14,3),true)`

(Note that I included the volatile mechanism even though you don't need it here, since the way you'd be using it is a special case where volatile needn't be declared. This function should be considered volatile unless you know better.)

But, this is not really necessary.

**(2)** My usual way to generate a 1-k array of integers is to do something like:

```
=COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,k))
```

(Following your lead, uses a row array, though I tend to use columns. Must be in an array formula, obviously.)

**(3)** But what you're really trying to do is average the k smallest values in an array.  For that I'd just do this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(RANK(A1:Z1,A1:Z1,1)+COLUMN(A1:Z1)/COLUMNS(A1:Z1)<=SMALL(RANK(A1:Z1,A1:Z1,1)+COLUMN(A1:Z1)/COLUMNS(A1:Z1),10),A1:Z1,""))
```

where `A1:Z1` is the array and 10 is the number of items to include, entered as an array formula.

The reason you can't just use SMALL as a test for inclusion, as you no doubt already know, is that the kth item might be one of several with the same value. So, I use RANK to assign each value an integer (if they're already integers, this isn't necessary) then I add a fraction based on order of appearance to produce a id for each value that maintains its position: `RANK(A1:Z1,A1:Z1,1)+COLUMN(A1:Z1)/COLUMNS(A1:Z1)` If a value's id is one of the smallest (in my example, the smallest 10) the value is included, otherwise I pass `""` to the AVERAGE function.

To get the number of items to use (in place of the '10' in my example), you could either use your table-lookup or use a rule such as `MAX(1,MIN(10,COUNT(A1:Z1)-1))`.

So, the final formula, using your range, might be:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(RANK($N9:AA9,$N9:AA9,1)+COLUMN($N9:AA9)/COLUMNS($N9:AA9)<=SMALL(RANK($N9:AA9,$N9:AA9,1)+COLUMN($N9:AA9)/COLUMNS($N9:AA9),MAX(1,MIN(10,COUNT($N9:AA9)-1))),$N9:AA9,""))
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and creative thinking. I plugged this in and followed your formula and I think it will work with one exception - the blank cells return `#N/A` for the `RANK` functions. I'm a little stumped on how to avoid the N/A for blank cells. Thanks again for your thoughtful analysis.

Comment: @p0werenner You could replace RANK($N9:AA9,$N9:AA9,1)with IFERROR(RANK($N9:AA9,$N9:AA9,1),COUNT($N9:AA9)+1)